# CSS and JS Files Not Found Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento2

Magento CSS and JS files are not found.

I have just installed Magento 2.3, The issue is that the JS and CSS files are not located at what they are supposed to be and because of that i am getting not found error when access magento admin panel, Here is the sc shot: https://prnt.sc/mk1ltx

I also have checked the directory like require js which is empty, Here is the sc shot: https://prnt.sc/mk1jng

Please help, Thanks

Comment: Try https://magento.stackexchange.com/ they are a specialized exchange for that type of question, StackOverflow is used for coding/programming questions.

Comment: Danillo Cabello can  u please move it in the magento stack overflow As i am new user so i can't

Comment: I can't either, I am not sure how to proceed, I believe you would have to close this one and reopen there.

Comment: if you have access to shell, try **bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**. It will re-deploy your static files

Comment: run `sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated` on magento root folder